# Oracle Apex, How to get data on oracle apex interactive report selecting on checkbox

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

[image]

I want to get data when in check the checkbox below I am using oracle apex interactive report data comes from data base.

It is working when I checked the checkbox and then click save button. But I want that its show data in interactive report when I click on checkbox. Can anyone help me how It will work?

I attached picture for clarification.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to region's properties, under "SQL query" you'll see **Page items to submit** property - put name of those checkboxes in there, separated by comma. For example:

```
P1_CB_KONSTRUKTION,P1_CB_NC_PROGRAMM,P1_CB_FRASE
```

Comment: Sir, These  name also comes from data base against their ID.

Comment: Whatever they are, you have to submit their values to session state. I have no idea how items' real names are, but - that's what you should do (if you want to make it work).